# Protocol Buffer - merge binary data files with the same .proto file to the one file

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a lot of data files (almost 150) in binary structure created according the .proto scheme of Protocol Buffer. Is there any efficient solution how to merge all the files to just one big binary data file without losing any information?

Comment: Do you have the scheme?

Comment: Yes, I have the scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your scheme allows it, you could combine existing data.

### The Scheme

```
message People {
  repeated Person person = 1;
}
message Person {
  required int32 id = 1;
  required string name = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

### Existing Data

Two existing binary files conataining a `Person`, each.

- `person1.bin`
- `person2.bin`

### Python Code

```
import p_pb2

people = p_pb2.People()
people.person.add().ParseFromString(open("person1.bin", "rb").read())
people.person.add().ParseFromString(open("person2.bin", "rb").read())
with open("people.bin", "wb") as o:
    o.write(people.SerializeToString())
```

### Combined Data

Now the file `people.bin` contains a `People` instance including both `Person` instances.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will definitely try it as soon as possible! Nevertheless it makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunately I found out that proto schema hadn't any wrapper class (the file was pretty large and there wasn't possible to store every rows in one wrapped class), so it was encrypted as BASE64 and separated by the new lines.

Because of this format it was quite easy to merge the files I wanted to merge. Just append these files.

Thanks anyway for your piece of advice!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Likor, I can just combine the binaries using `cat proto1.bin proto1.bin > combined_proto.bin` then de-serialize the binary to string.